# How to set focus on Input Angular2 Form

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an Input in angular2/Ionic2 form

```
<input #input1 autofocus type="text" [ngModel]='searchString' name='searchText' required minlength="3" (ngModelChange)="onInputChange($event)">
```

I want to set focus on it when page/route change.

`nativeElement.focus()` is not working as `@ViewChild(#input1)` gives angular2 element not native html element.

Comment: it does give nativeElement can you replicate this issue in stacblitz

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/how-can-i-select-an-element-in-a-component-template

Answer (score 1):

what is 'autofocus' for? is not necessary

```js
@ViewChild ('input1') el: ElementRef; // the # is used in html only

....

async ngOnInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.el.nativeElement.focus(); // with ElementRef should work, but if you encounter any problem just use 'any' type
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I have to wrap this.el.nativeElement.focus(); inside setTimeout

Comment: Edited for setTimeout (1 sec)

Comment: Also it is better to use ngAfterViewInit

Comment: Do it on ngAfterViewInit event and no need in setting the timer!